# AJAX Horizontal scrolling the page

Tags: css, ajax, html, preload

I have to build a site like France24.com, There is a navigation on the left and two arrows on sides for scrolling to the sides. when you click on the arrows or one of navigation items , the related page (preloads) and appears without refreshing the page. How to do that? Is there any usable framework or sample for this?

Regards

Comment: AJAX does not "Horizontal scroll pages". Also, StackOverflow is not for code inspiration. I recommend you to edit you question and find a better suiting title and maybe try your best with the code and post what you got. Else your question will get closed by not constructive by someone else. :)

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the website, I see what you are trying to do.  I see a way to do this, which is through a simple JQuery method load() ( http://api.jquery.com/load/ ).  This behaves like get(), so on clicking the arrow, an event could be triggered where you can load another piece of HTML code in place of the one the user is currently looking at.

If you need dynamic content to load instead of a simple static HTML code, it's possible to achieve that by filling in the dynamic part into the HTML code that you want to load before actually loading it.  A library that you can use to achieve something like this is React js, developed by FB.  Good luck!